# Is there firefox extensions for saving to favorits post-form result? e.g. search result that going via post form?

Tags: firefox

Is there firefox extensions for saving to favorits post-form result? e.g. search result that going via post form?

It very hard to alway fill big forms with many fields every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [roboform for Firefox](http://www.roboform.com/platforms/browsers/firefox), with it you can:

- Create/Edit/Save of the Bookmarks was added.
- Edit of local Identities was added.
- Manual Save operation of the current document fields was added.
- Reset/Clear fields commands were added.

Comment: I don't want to fill foms automaticaly, i want to save one post-post form to bookmarks and load every time the same form.